# Issue with OpenCV Warp perspective and euclidean distance

Tags: java, c#, android, opencv, euclidean-distance

My program uses a C# port of OpenCV to find the largest rectangle in the scene and warps the perspective. It almost works, but has one very annoying bug that I just can't figure out.

Using it on a square works perfectly, but it will only work correctly on rectangles in one orientation.

For example, if I give it an image of a note card, I get:
[image]

But if I rotate that same note card 90 degrees, I get this:

[image]

I know the code for finding rectangles is correct, so it has to be in the warp perspective process which looks like this:

```
public Mat GetPerspective (List<Point> corners, Mat sub)
{
    //Pretty sure these four lines are the problem
    double top = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(corners[0].x - corners[1].x, 2) + Math.Pow(corners[0].y - corners[1].y, 2));
    double right = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(corners[1].x - corners[2].x, 2) + Math.Pow(corners[1].y - corners[2].y, 2));
    double bottom = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(corners[2].x - corners[3].x, 2) + Math.Pow(corners[2].y - corners[3].y, 2));
    double left = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(corners[3].x - corners[1].x, 2) + Math.Pow(corners[3].y - corners[1].y, 2));

    Mat quad = Mat.zeros(new Size(Math.Max(top, bottom), Math.Max(left, right)), CvType.CV_8UC3);
    List<Point> result_points = new List<Point>();

    result_points.Add(new Point(0,0));
    result_points.Add(new Point(quad.cols(), 0));
    result_points.Add(new Point(quad.cols(), quad.rows()));
    result_points.Add(new Point(0, quad.rows()));

    Mat cornerPts = Converters.vector_Point2f_to_Mat(corners);
    Mat resultPts = Converters.vector_Point2f_to_Mat(result_points);

    Mat transformation = Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform(cornerPts, resultPts);
    Imgproc.warpPerspective(sub, quad, transformation, quad.size());
    return quad;
}
```

Comment: How is this related to Java and Android?

Comment: im developing within unity using the OpenCv for unity port by enox software which is a direct port of opencv java. so usually when i run into a problem its easier to look into the java documentation rather than other c# ports. sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
long[] tl = corners[0];

long[] tr = corners[1];

long[] br = corners[2];

long[] bl = corners[3];

float widthA = (float) Math.sqrt((Math.pow((br[0] - bl[0]), 2)) + Math.pow((br[1] - bl[1]), 2));

float widthB = (float) Math.sqrt((Math.pow((tr[0] - tl[0]), 2)) + Math.pow((tr[1] - tl[1]), 2));

int maxWidth = (int) Math.max((widthA), (widthB));

float heightA = (float) Math.sqrt((Math.pow((tr[0] - br[0]), 2)) + Math.pow((tr[1] - br[1]), 2));

float heightB = (float) Math.sqrt((Math.pow((tl[0] - bl[0]), 2)) + Math.pow((tl[1] - bl[1]), 2));

int maxHeight = (int) Math.max(heightA, heightB);
```

Comment: While code only answers might provide a solution, they are considers as not good answers. Please give additonal information. Explain what your code does and why you used / change specific commands.

Answer (score 0):

You just mispronounced the left point in your presentation

```
enter code here
public Mat GetPerspective(List<Point> corners, Mat sub)
{
    //Pretty sure these four lines are the problem
    double top = System.Math.Sqrt(System.Math.Pow(corners[0].x - corners[1].x, 2) + System.Math.Pow(corners[0].y - corners[1].y, 2));
    double right = System.Math.Sqrt(System.Math.Pow(corners[1].x - corners[2].x, 2) + System.Math.Pow(corners[1].y - corners[2].y, 2));
    double bottom = System.Math.Sqrt(System.Math.Pow(corners[2].x - corners[3].x, 2) + System.Math.Pow(corners[2].y - corners[3].y, 2));
    double left = System.Math.Sqrt(System.Math.Pow(corners[3].x - corners[0].x, 2) + System.Math.Pow(corners[3].y - corners[0].y, 2));

    Mat quad = Mat.zeros(new Size(System.Math.Max(top, bottom), System.Math.Max(left, right)), CvType.CV_8UC3);
    List<Point> result_points = new List<Point>();

    result_points.Add(new Point(0, 0));
    result_points.Add(new Point(quad.cols(), 0));
    result_points.Add(new Point(quad.cols(), quad.rows()));
    result_points.Add(new Point(0, quad.rows()));

    Mat cornerPts = OpenCVForUnity.UtilsModule.Converters.vector_Point2f_to_Mat(corners);
    Mat resultPts = OpenCVForUnity.UtilsModule.Converters.vector_Point2f_to_Mat(result_points);

    Mat transformation = Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform(cornerPts, resultPts);
    Imgproc.warpPerspective(sub, quad, transformation, quad.size());
    return quad;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcQRf.png)